# Compress CSS file in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a website made with NUXT (VUE framework) and when compiling it, it doesn't compress the CSS files, giving me a very long HTML code.

https://www.tiroconarco.link/

I generate the files with a **yarn generate**, I suppose that I must put something in the configuration files so that it compresses the CSS.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: The css in your website is its minified version. What do you mean by compressing?

Comment: Under the commented information of Github, start a code " html{box-sizing:border-box;overflow-y:scroll; ......... "

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS contents are already compressed by the Nuxt build process. But stylesheets are inlined in your HTML page for performance purpose, to avoid loading another CSS file.

(see [default optimization options](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#htmlminify))

You can extract all your CSS to an external single file by configuration as below:

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  }
}
```

See more about `extractCSS` on docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#extractcss